# Call to a member function format() on a non-object Error

Tags: php

I am getting this error as per subjected and the error is from the code below.

Can anyone please advise what is wrong with it? 
Using PHP 5.3
Not much of a coder, and would appreciate any help. Thanks.
It is trying to compare dates.

Please see below code :

```
 $delivrance_diff = (int)date_diff(date_create($_SESSION['passport_date2'].'-'.month_to_mm($_SESSION['passport_date1']).'-'.$_SESSION['passport_date']), date_create('today'))->format("%r%a");

 $expiry_diff =  (int)date_diff(date_create('today'), date_create($_SESSION['passport_exp2'].'-'.month_to_mm($_SESSION['passport_exp1']).'-'.$_SESSION['passport_exp']))->format("%r%a");

 $exp_diff =  (int)date_diff(date_create($_SESSION['passport_date2'].'-'.month_to_mm($_SESSION['passport_date1']).'-'.$_SESSION['passport_date']), date_create($_SESSION['passport_exp2'].'-'.month_to_mm($_SESSION['passport_exp1']).'-'.$_SESSION['passport_exp']))->format("%r%a");
```

Comment: What is "%r%a"?

Comment: Also, this seems to be a framework of some sort, any hint as to what it is?

Comment: Please, use a library like carbon to help you out with this stuff.  google nesbot carbon.

Comment: Thanks guys, will look into it. @Adam I do not know what %r%a does, i got the code like this and working around it.

Comment: No framework, plain php.

Answer (score 0):

One of your date_create() doesn't return a valid DateTime object, maybe because the input is wrong, its YEAR-MONTH-DAY. so date_diff returns no DateTime object to be formated.

Comment: Thanks Tom. If i would want to rewrite this to be proper, how should i structure the DateTime object?